# Spring InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid mime type "multipart/mixed; boundary==_123456789": Invalid token character '=' in token "=_123456789"

Tags: java, spring, rest, multipart

I use Spring to call a REST API which reply with header that contains "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary==_123456789".

My problem is that Spring try to parse the Content-Type and throw InvalidMediaTypeException due to '=' in boundary token.

Is there a way to disable this checking (or any workaround) ?

These are my logs :

```
org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid mime type "multipart/mixed; boundary==_11204303fda4403b6a72d61500081354": Invalid token character '=' in token "=_11204303fda4403b6a72d61500081354"
    at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:620)
    at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.getContentType(HttpHeaders.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.getContentType(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1037)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1020)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:778)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:468)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way by using `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` to modify the boundary parameter and add double quote.

```
public class MultipartMixedBoundaryRewritingInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    private Pattern multipartMixedHeaderPattern = Pattern.compile("^multipart/mixed;\\s?boundary=(.*?)$");

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
        
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = response.getHeaders();
        // Do not use .getHeaders().getContentType() since it checks everything and raises an exception on the invalid boundary
        String contentType = response.getHeaders().getFirst("Content-Type");
        Matcher matcher = multipartMixedHeaderPattern.matcher(contentType);
        if (contentType != null && matcher.matches()) {
            String boundaryParameter = matcher.group(1);
            try {
                responseHeaders.getContentType();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                if (boundaryParameter != null && !isQuotedString(boundaryParameter)) {
                    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
                    parameters.put("boundary", String.format("\"%s\"", boundaryParameter));
                    MediaType fixedContentType = new MediaType(MediaType.MULTIPART_MIXED, parameters);
                    response.getHeaders().setContentType(fixedContentType);
                }
            }
        }
        return response;
    }

    private boolean isQuotedString(String s) {
        return s.length() > 2 && ((s.startsWith("\"") && s.endsWith("\"")) || (s.startsWith("'") && s.endsWith("'")));
    }
}
```

And configuring the `restTemplate`

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        configureRestTemplateInterceptors(restTemplate);
        return restTemplate;
    }

    private void configureRestTemplateInterceptors(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = restTemplate.getInterceptors();
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(interceptors)) {
                interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        interceptors.add(new MultipartMixedBoundaryRewritingInterceptor());
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RFC1341 applies to MIME types in email.

For HTTP the specification is in [RFC2616 § 2.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-2.2), and that document specifies that "token separators" can be included as values only if the value is enclosed in quotes.  It is possible that whatever is creating that boundary string is using the RFC1341 definition instead of the (correct) RFC2616 spec.

The header should be

```
multipart/mixed; boundary="=_11204303fda4403b6a72d61500081354"
```

BTW, the code that throws the exception is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/0783f0762d72df70572aaceeee099c3ec4b7e019/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/MimeType.java#L54) in method `checkToken()`.  That's in the latest version, looks like you have an earlier version of Spring.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I take a look with older spring behaviour

Comment: I mentioned the version only because the source given in your stack trace doesn't match the current source.  I'm sure it will exhibit the same behavior in all versions, since `checkToken()` explicitly states it is implementing the restrictions in RFC2616.